# Basic Algebra in Thompson's "Calculus Made Easy"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am getting back into math and reading the public domain version of "Calculus Made Easy" by Silvanus Thompson. I am enjoying it however my brain is getting tired, and I'm getting stuck on page 23, where he is going over the case of differentiating a negative power, when he makes an algebraic step that I have some questions about. He says,

Let $y = x^{-2}$. Then proceed as before:

$y + dy = (x +dx)^{-2} = x^{-2}(1+\frac{dx}{x})^{-2}$.

My question is: Isn't it the rule that we *can't* factor a binomial like that? And also, if factoring like that is allowed, wouldn't factoring out $x^{-2}$ leave us with something else in the parentheses? How is he getting from that one step to the other? I am getting tired. What am I missing or seeing incorrectly? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you aware of exponent law $(ab) ^n=a^nb^n$? That is the basis of the factorization in your post.

Comment: He’s writing $x+y =x\left(1+ \frac yx\right)$.

Comment: $(x-dx)^{-2}=(x(1-\frac{dx}{x}))^{-2}$  and then applying the exponent law mentioned by @ParamanandSingh, $x^{-2}(1-\frac{dx}{x})^{-2}$

Comment: No wonder, you're confused. What you are reading is complete  nonsense. Differentials have their place in  algebraic function fields and other areas at the advanced graduate level. about ten levels above where you are now. All that author is doing is making a sloppy approximation. As a professional academic, I should be very opposed, even horrified, by book burning but if you need help in throwing that disgaceful piece of garbage into the dumpster, just let me know.

Comment: @P.Lawrence: while I can understand your views (which are similar to mine for such calculus texts), I think it is best to avoid dramatic language (as some users may get offended). In short the best advice to OP here is to get a new and better calculus textbook and there are many recommendations already available on mathse.